# How to express the the stochastic integral into an Ito process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I am facing problem while trying to express the following stochastic integral into an Ito process.

$$X_{t} = e^{-t}\int_{0}^{t}e^{u}dW_{u}$$

I would like to express the above as
$dX_{t} = \Theta dt + \Delta dW_{t}$.
I started with expressing the integral part into
$e^{t}W_{t}-\int_{0}^{t} e^{u} W_{u}du$.
However, I am stuck as if I continue with the above, I will get

$$e^{-t} \int_{0}^{t} e^{u} W_{u}du + dW_{t}-W_{t}dt$$

This is not of the form I needed.
May I know which step I have done wrong and how to go from here please?

Answer (score 2):

Recall the Itô product rule:
$$d(YZ)_t = Y_t dZ_t + Z_t dY_t + dY_t dZ_t$$
Thus, for your process,
\begin{align}
dX_t = e^{-t} e^t dW_t -e^{-t} \left( \int_0^t e^u dW_u \right) dt= dW_t - X_t dt 
\end{align}

Comment: thank you so much for your response. If you don't mind, I would also like to ask that in this case, does it mean by initial approach was wrong and should apply chain rule straightaway?

Comment: @user515454 you integrated by parts correctly, but then you have to compute the differential, meaning you'd have to apply Itô's formula somehow in your computation

Comment: thank you a lot for your patience in explaining, Jose! :)